# Projection system for India or Indian subcontinent with metric system

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, india

I am creating a buffer around my geometries using QGIS.
The unit of the buffer is shown in degrees because the projection system is WGS84.

I need to change the projection system so that unit for buffer comes in metric system (I want to add 10-meter buffer).

Which projection system should I use? My shapefile contains geometries are from India.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your localization

Take a look at this site: https://epsg.io/?q=India

Comment: Thanks , Its EPSG:24378